# Integrate Facebook SDK in android and retrieve user's email

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to retrieve logged in user email. This is what I tied, but not retrieving the email. I could retrieve only **id, first name, last name** but not the **email**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            try {
                                String userEmail = object.getString("email");
                                String userId = object.getString("id");
                                emailEditText.setText(userEmail);
                                new SignupTask(SignupActivity.this, userId, userEmail).execute();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email"); // Parámetros que pedimos a facebook
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
```

What do I have missed....

Comment: Is it happening for all user or few?? Because most of the FB users are logged in via phone number but not email. So you will get null value for such users

Comment: No, I'm jst testing with the emulator. I logged using email

Comment: Try to use real device and check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29379794/5515371

Comment: Try this solution, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196682/facebook-android-sdk-4-5-0-get-email-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ohk..try this code its working for me...    

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb);
        loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        if (netWorkStatus) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    //Store Facebook data to webservice .
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                    // Application code
                                    try {
                                        // String picture = object.getString("picture");
                                        //JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(picture);
                                        //JSONObject dataObj = jobj.getJSONObject("data");

                                        name = object.getString("name");
                                        userEmail = object.getString("email");
                                        //String url = dataObj.getString("url").replace("\\", "");

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code

                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: I tried it. But same issue was there. The reason for happen this was. I have used ReadPermission and PublishPermission at once

Answer (score 0):

```
CallbackManager callbackManager ;

//in OnCreate  initialize it
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


//after that overide onActivityResult
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: @ Mohammed Atif, try this code it would be helped you, let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: This code is there in my code. I can retrieve  id, first name, last name but not the email

Comment: @Senps, it may be possible which email your using its not vrified. Have you tried with another one

Comment: @Senps, i have posted my code..its works for me..try it