# Facebook login get user birthday and email android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the user email and birthday when user uses facebook login for my app.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginButton facebookLoginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile", "user_birthday"));

        facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error
                            } else {
                                String email = me.optString("email");
                                String name = me.optString("name");
                                String birthday = me.optString("user_birthday");

                                System.out.println(email);
                                System.out.println(name);
                                System.out.println(birthday);
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();


            String userID = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            String AuthToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            System.out.println(userID);
            System.out.println(AuthToken);

        }
```

Only name, userID and AuthToken is printed successfully, I am not getting values for birthday and email (I use email for my facebook account and provided birthday so there should be value).

Am i using the permission wrong?

Comment: You can refer this link for email and birthday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196682/facebook-android-sdk-4-5-0-get-email-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Replace your GraphRequest code with This**

```
GraphRequest mGraphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            // handle error
                        } else {
                            String email = me.optString("email");
                            String name = me.optString("name");
                            String birthday = me.optString("user_birthday");

                            System.out.println(email);
                            System.out.println(name);
                            System.out.println(birthday);
                        }
                    }
                });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            mGraphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            mGraphRequest.executeAsync();


        String userID = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
        String AuthToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
        System.out.println(userID);
        System.out.println(AuthToken);

    }
```

Comment: Pleasure is all mine friend :)

Comment: Now birthday is not available in fb login