# facebook api How to get the email and the phoneNumber

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm actually using the firebase auth.
so I want to integrate the facebook login to work in parallel with the firebase authentication.
Well, my question is how to get the Email and the phone number from the current user in condition if there are not an email it will get the phone number.
this is my Activity code:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult>callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            nextActivity(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                nextActivity(newProfile);

            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
        callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                nextActivity(profile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in ....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        };
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile","user_friends");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile =Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        nextActivity(profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode,intent);

    }

    private void nextActivity(Profile profile) {
        if (profile != null) {
            Intent main = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
            main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString());
            startActivity(main);
        }
    }}
```

**EDIT:** the solution is that the phone number is that the phone number is not available in the Facebook api.
So to get the email id I used this **solution** : 
[Facebook Android SDK 4.5.0 get email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196682/facebook-android-sdk-4-5-0-get-email-address)

Comment: You can try Graph to get email id.

Comment: You don’t get a phone number, that info is not available via API.

Comment: and the phone number , cause in facebook there are many account without an email

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196682/facebook-android-sdk-4-5-0-get-email-address

Comment: ahh ok Mr CBroe thanks so do you have a solution for the email id please ?

Comment: so the phone number is not available in the facebook api, I will get your solution mr Michal thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> facebook api How to get the email and the phoneNumber

**Update:** The user_address and user_mobile_phone permissions have been removed. Please see this post for more info.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/